# How to serialize a large file?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to serialize a large file of size 85MB but I keep getting an out of memory exception. Initially this code was serializing in memory, but when I changed to disk it solved some of my problems but not with larger files. Below is my code:

```
Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter() ' Create a binary formatter for this stream.
Using sw As New StreamWriter(FileName)
    bf.Serialize(sw.BaseStream, obj) 
    sw.Close()
End Using
```

How can I avoid this exception? I am using VB.Net 2010. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: .NET has a limitation of a maximum of 2GB per object in memory. Are you doing anything else besides serializing which can cause the object to grow beyond 2GB. Can you post the exact exception and full stack trace.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to pull down a memory profiler and keep an eye on your LOH, snapshot before serializing, snapshot after, do a comparison. A good profiler with a free trial is [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/?fromMenu)

Comment: "at System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)     at System.Convert.ToBase64String(Byte[] inArray, Int32 offset, Int32 length, Base64FormattingOptions options)     at System.Convert.ToBase64String(Byte[] inArray)     at System.Data.Common.ObjectStorage.ConvertObjectToXml(Object value)     at System.Data.XmlDataTreeWriter.XmlDataRowWriter(DataRow row, String encodedTableName)     at System.Data.XmlDataTreeWriter.SaveDiffgramData(XmlWriter xw, Hashtable rowsOrder)     at

Comment: The object actually grows to 193GB if I check using:                               Dim a = GC.GetTotalMemory(False)

Comment: By any chance is your object made up of a huge number of smaller unique objects?

Comment: No, its not. It is just one massive file containing text

Comment: you are getting a big string from where? if it is pure text, you can use File.WriteAllText(). And seriously: 193 GB? Do you mean MB?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but because you used `Using sw` you don't need to do `sw.Close()`

Comment: 193MB doesn't sound too worrisime: 85MB with one-byte encoding, 170MB `char` (2-byte) encoding, plus a little overhead.

Comment: What this question really needs to be answerable is a [mcve]. We're just left to guessing right now what `obj` is.

Comment: Not sure if it'll make any difference, but what if you try to serialize using a `FileStream` instead?

Comment: MicroVirus may you help with the suggested code. The issue is my program must be able to serialize contents of a file and save them in another file. For smaller (standard) word documents the program is working fine. It is when I tried stress testing with an 80MB file (so I used an ISO file of some installer package, since I could not quickly lay my hands on a word document of that size ) and I got the out of memory exception.